# How do I include libcurl in a custom local library to be used by local C applications

Tags: c, cmake, static-libraries, libcurl

I'm building a small local C library for various utility functions, including one to download files via libcurl.  I will be using this utils library in various other C applications, but I would like the libcurl details to be hidden from those applications.

I have two cmake projects, "localutils" and "daytrading".  localutils is correctly linking to a specific version of libcurl and unit tests are succeeding.  This project is being "installed" to /usr/local/lib/localutils and /usr/local/include/localutils.  daytrading is finding the localutils library, but I'm seeing "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" errors when building daytrading that refer to the libcurl functions being used.

```
====================[ Build | update | Debug ]==================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/adam/c/daytrading/cmake-build-debug --target update -- -j 2
[ 66%] Built target tradingdays
[ 66%] Built target symbols
[ 83%] Linking C executable ../bin/update
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
      _download_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
  "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
      _download_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
  "_curl_easy_perform", referenced from:
      _download_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
  "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
      _download_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
  "_curl_version_info", referenced from:
      _download_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
  "_zip_fclose", referenced from:
      _extract_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
  "_zip_fopen_index", referenced from:
      _extract_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
  "_zip_fread", referenced from:
      _extract_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
  "_zip_get_num_entries", referenced from:
      _extract_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
  "_zip_open", referenced from:
      _extract_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
  "_zip_stat_index", referenced from:
      _extract_file in libfiles.a(files.c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [../bin/update] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/update.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/update.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [update] Error 2
```

localutils CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(localutils C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../bin)

include_directories(
        /usr/local/opt/curl/include/curl
        /usr/local/include)

link_directories(
        /usr/local/opt/curl/lib
        /usr/local/lib)

add_library(types src/types/comparers.c src/types/dict.c src/types/list.c)
add_library(files src/files/files.c)

find_library(CURL_LIB curl PATH /usr/local/opt/curl/lib NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_library(ZIP_LIB zip PATH /usr/local/lib/libzip NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
target_link_libraries(files ${CURL_LIB} ${ZIP_LIB})

add_executable(runtests tests/run.c tests/ListTests.c tests/DictionaryTests.c tests/FileTests.c)
target_link_libraries(runtests types files)

set_target_properties(types PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "src/types/types.h;src/types/comparers.h;src/types/list.h;src/types/dict.h")
set_target_properties(files PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "src/files/files.h")

INSTALL(TARGETS types files
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION         /usr/local/lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION         /usr/local/lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION   /usr/local/include/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

daytrading CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(daytrading C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../bin)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

find_library(TYPES_LIB types PATH /usr/local/lib/localutils NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_library(FILES_LIB files PATH /usr/local/lib/localutils NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

add_library(symbols src/symbols.c)
add_library(tradingdays src/tradingdays.c)

add_executable(update src/update.c)
target_link_libraries(update symbols tradingdays ${TYPES_LIB} ${FILES_LIB})
```

I was hoping that all of those libcurl details would be compiled into the "files" library of localutils, and that daytrading wouldn't even be aware that libcurl was involved.  So far, the only way I've been able to make anything compile is by adding the same references to libcurl (and libzip) to the daytrading CMakeLists.txt file as well, which I was hoping to avoid.

I'm probably misunderstanding something fundamental about linking in general, or cmake for that matter.